# setOnClickListener inside CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am trying to get OnClickListener to work inside my CustomAdapter but nothing happens in my case.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(inflater == null){
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if(view==null){
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_blog,viewGroup,false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    if(lv!=null){
            lv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(view.getContext());
                d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                d.show();
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: do you have a listview inside a listview? Can you also post your layout xmls

Comment: Debug and put a breakpoint on the line `setOnClickListener` and see if it ever hits that line.

Comment: You set an ItemClickListner on the listview that the adapter is bound to. Not within the Adapter

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you have a ListView inside of your lLstItemView. What you are doing right now is getting your list item and then trying to find a ListView inside of it to set your click listener.

If you actually want to set a click listener on the whole list then you should either be doing this in your activity or you could set it by adding the clickListener or the parent `viewGroup` that is passed in as a parameter:

```
viewGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(view.getContext());
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    d.show();
  }
});
```

If you want to set the click listener on the list item then you should set the clickListener on your listView in you activity code using `ListView.setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener)`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(view.getContext());
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    d.show();
  }
});
```

If you want to set the click listener on a view inside of the list item then make sure you are getting the correct child view by checking that the id of the view you are trying to get exists in `list_item_blog`.

Best of luck! Hope this helps.

Comment: No... You should use `listview.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: that's true, if you want to set it on the whole item you should use `setOnItemClickListener` Ill update my answer.